# Не выполняется Python скрипт из php

Tags: php, python

```
$command = 'source ~/myenv/bin/activate && python main.py 100458';
echo shell_exec($command);
```

Сначала выбираю среду, потом запускаю скрипт. Нет вывода и сам скрипт не выполняется. Из командной строки все выполняется. Рабочая директория правильная.

Comment: работает ли `\`~/myenv/bin/python main.py 100458\``?

Answer (score 1):

Функция [shell_exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) выполняет свой аргумент с помощью POSIX-совместимого интерпретатора `/bin/sh`. У такого интерпретатора может не быть встроенной команды [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-source). Вам следует заменить это слово на обычную точку.

В вашем терминале это команда работает, поскольку там, скорее всего, используется интерпретатор `/bin/bash`, у которого гораздо больше возможностей имеется.

Comment: Так? `$command = '.~/myenv/bin/activate && python main.py 100458';`

Comment: пробел нужен после первой точки обязательно

Comment: что с пробелом, что без, ничего не меняется

Comment: сам activate скрипт внутри может башизмы использовать (может быть недостаточно `source` на `.` заменить). Хотя для bash, zsh, dash как есть должен работать.  Лучше venv/bin/python напрямую запустить.